# Retrofit post request, url already has parameter, body has request parameter, how to define the request interface use?

Tags: android, retrofit

jQuery request format(Web):

```js
$.ajax({
method:'POST',
  url: '/getData/item?num=10&page=5',
  data: JSON.stringify({"name":"1012","pwd":”123456}),
contentType:'application/json',
  success: function() {alert('great')}
});
```

=> ? 
Retrofit request format(Android):

```
public interface IDataService{
    @POST("/getData/item")
    Observable<List<MailDataBean> getData(@Field("num") int num,@Field("page") int page, @Body String body);
}
```

Ref: com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model:

```
public class Credentials
{
    public String name;
    public String pwd;
}
```

Now change your code to this:

```
public interface IDataService{
        @POST("/getData/item")
        Observable<List<MailDataBean> getData(@Query("num") String num, @Query("page") String page, @Body Credentials credentials);
    }
```

Hope it helps you.